# Autocomplete using data from mysql in play?

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, playframework, jquery-autocomplete

I'm working on a project using the play! framework and I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to connect a basic jquery autocomplete to use mysql database as the datasource and retrieve information from it. Has anyone tried this before ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jqueryui autocomplete, you just have to set an input field with a special class "autocomplete" :

```
<input type="text" class="ui-state-default autocomplete" name="object.name" value="" />
```

Then you can use this jquery code to setup the autocomplete

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.autocomplete').each( function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    // Set-up the autocomplete widget.
    $(this).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source : function(req, resp) {
          $.getJSON("@{MyController.getObjects()}?term=" + req.term , req, function(data) {
            var suggestions = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
              var obj = {};
              obj.label = val.name;
              obj.id = val.id;
              suggestions.push(obj);
            });
            resp(suggestions);
          });
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Here you call the method getObjects on controller "MyController". This method looks like

```
public static void getObjects(final String term) {
    renderJSON(MyObject.findByName(term, AUTOCOMPLETE_MAX));
}
```

where "findByName" is a method in your model object that search objects by name. AUTOCOMPLETE_MAX is a const that defines the maximum number of objects you want to retrieve.

The controller method getObjects return a json object that is called "val" in the javascript. Note that you have to map values from this object to an object with a "label" and an "id" that can be managed by jquery autocomplete.

With this solution, you will get back the object name in your controller validation method. I like this solution because you can then search the object by name in the controller allowing a user to choose something wihtout using the autocomplete list. You will then validate the name in the controller validation method.

You have another solution based on id on lunatech site : http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/07/05/jquery-ui-ajax-autocomplete-playframework

Answer (score -1):

Try using jquery-UI autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

This could help

In the auto complete jquery UI, you can give input(sources) as string, array or javascript callback.

In your case, you can use callback as the source and can use ajax to get the data from the mysql.

I haven't tried it, but I guess it should work.

Comment: The thing is that I need help in linking the autocomplete to the database. The code snippet is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Could you pls provide me with a link of using ajax to get data from mysql ?

Comment: Which CGI are you using in the server side?

Comment: What do u mean by CGI in server side ?